# Having issues with linking to boost library (C++ in Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I have been banging my head on this for a few days now. I tried downloading and compiling the latest boost 1.67.0, to include

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
```

But I got the errors seen below when trying to compile (one thing I noticed about it is that the path has slashes going the wrong way in the error log and Im not sure how to fix that?

I tried compiling with standard cmd and also Visual Studio 2013 prompt (same result).

I then tried grabbing the precompiled version from boost site

```
boost_1_67_0-msvc-12.0-32.exe
```

And am still getting the same problem. The #include text is not underlined in the editor. And I have additional include directories pointing to:

```
C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0
```

and Linker Additional Library Directories to

```
C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? If I comment out the #include lines for boost the code compiles without any issues and program runs. My code doesnt use anything from boost yet, so the only boost related stuff in there are the 3 #include lines.

Errors are:

> 1>  MyForm.cpp
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(65): error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(72): error C2660: 'boost::process::process_error::process_error' : function does not take 2 arguments
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(77): error C2660: 'boost::process::process_error::process_error' : function does not take 2 arguments
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(82): error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'std::error_code' to 'boost::process::process_error'
>   1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(88): error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'const std::error_code' to 'boost::process::process_error'
>   1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(94): error C2660: 'boost::process::process_error::process_error' : function does not take 2 arguments
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(97): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Char'
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(97): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'null_char'
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(97): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(98): error C2144: syntax error : 'char' should be preceded by ';'
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(98): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(99): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(99): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(101): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Char'
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(101): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'equal_sign'
>   1>C:\VisualStudioLibraries\boost_1_67_0\boost/process/detail/config.hpp(101): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Thank you all very much.

Comment: I would back off and use an older boost if you are stuck with Visual Studio 2013. I know that boost-1.64 works since I use that with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Ill give that a shot. Thanks! How about my linking? Those two are the only things that need to be set right? And those are the correct directories? Im still perplexed with Unix style "/" showing up in the error log as opposed to Windows style "\", thats cant be normal?

Comment: You can use either / or \ for most paths in Visual Studio. I use / almost all of the time.

Comment: Tried 1.64, same issue... Im using pre-compiled version, so cant be compilation. I even tried making a brand new blank project and simply adding #include    <boost/process.hpp> and compiling. No go.. hmm

Comment: A workaround for VS2013 not supporting 'noexcept' might be to define BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT before including boost headers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Im sure this is not the answer most will want to hear, but after trying for over a week to get it to work the only thing that ended up working was to move on to Visual Studio 2017. Everything linked and compiled fine there. Perhaps there is an issue with my VS2013 install (but everything else works flawlessly on it).